# Finding color spaces in PDF from linux command line

Tags: linux, image, pdf

I need to check if given PDF files are completely in CMYK color space. As you probably know, it is needed for printing.

Currently, it is done using GUI applications from Adobe, but it takes much time and we need to automate it with linux script.

I have tested many libraries, but each of them gave me invalid results or don't support newer PDF specs.

- I haven't found solution for that in `ghostscript`
- Exporting images from pdf is not good enough solution, since there are also paths and other media, which also need to be validated.
- `identify -verbose` gives invalid results (bad colorspace, but also bad DPI).

As far as i know, PDF can have different color spaces for elements in document and I want to check if **every** element is in CMYK.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by [pdfimages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfimages):

```
pdfimages -list filename.pdf
```

For a file with CMYK images, the output resembles:

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    5197  6732  cmyk    4   8  jpeg   no         5  0   600   601 32.3M  24%
   1     1 mask     5197  6732  -       1   1  jpeg   no         5  0   600   601 32.3M 775%
```

If all the images use an ICC profile, the output resembles:

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    5197  6732  icc     3   8  jpeg   no         8  0   600   601 7080K 6.9%
   1     1 mask     5197  6732  -       1   1  jpeg   no         8  0   600   601 7080K 166%
```

Comment: This solution appears to show information only about raster graphics included in a document, whereas the original question does not include such a constraint. Generally, PDF documents include vector graphics or text generated by some original format, such as vector drawing tool or text processing tool.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. `pdfimages` requires some other argument `image-root`. When I provide it, it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1):

From a coding standpoint you need access to a tool that will render every page in the PDF document, but instead of actually drawing things it would need to call bottlenecks on each and every PDF drawing command.

From there you would need to intercept all color operators, all gstate operators, all image operators and recurse on all Form XObjects and flag everything that isn't CMYK. Note that some color spaces will be tricky, for example you can have a paletted color space that uses a CMYK ICC colorspace under the hood. You can also run into the case where an app sets the color to an RGB color, never marks the page, then switches to CMYK before marking.